# How to show Book Opening and loading animation as in iBooks?

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, ibooks

I am trying to show a book opening animation as in iBooks. Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: This is now built into xCode 4.2.

Comment: Start a new project and choose 'Page Based Application".

Comment: You are talking about [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html), which gives you the nice page turning animation from iBooks. This question seems to be asking about the animation of the book 'unfolding' and opening when you choose a book from the bookshelf.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same requirement. I used [this](https://github.com/GuoLuchuan/iBooksOpen) library. Did some modification according to my need. Its working. Try it.