# Open Close (Unfolding) Book Animation In iBooks

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, transition, ibooks

My app currently basically wires the AQGridView project to the leaves project to make an iBooks (clone-esque) type PDF reader.  My problem is, I currently use the pageCurl transition from one view to the next, which is all well and good, but I want to take it to the next level.  Has anyone duplicated the iBooks unfolding/ folding book+cover animation?  Every question I see about this is just up voted twice with the most noobish and incoherent answers I've ever seen (example a: [How to show Book Opening and loading animation as in iBooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470219/how-to-show-book-opening-and-loading-animation-as-in-ibooks)).

Again, for clarification: I know HOW to read the PDF, I'm looking for a view TRANSITION.

EDIT 1: this recent question provided the first half of the answer (expanding the view to fill the screen) [File opening animation like in iBooks and Photos.app on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796821/file-opening-animation-like-in-ibooks-and-photos-app-on-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write the code for you, but what you're trying to do does sound like a keyframe animation. It's a lot more verbose than using UIView's wrapper to create animations, but you can do much more with it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I went with a more original implementation, but it is still an iBooks-esque animation.  And I've had a look at PSPDF, and I just think in the back of my mind that I shouldnt be paying for something I can do myself...